# How to delete particular array shown in grid and need to pass the id of the array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created the simple grid and I have remove button in every table row.

If any data in db, it's shown in the view and if user need to add more file,clicking on add new button,my modal array(Colum in code) push the empty array to view.

The problem is while clicking 3rd index array remove button it's remove the first index of the array.

And how to pass the id to service if any id present. Now I hard coded in delete method.

For understanding please view the image.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <form>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Knowledge Base</h3>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                        File Name
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Updated By
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Updated On
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        File
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmplt"></ng-template>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <input type="button" (click)="AddColum()" class="btn btn-info" value="Add New">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Save()" value="Save" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<ng-template #tmplt>

    <tr *ngFor="let kbase of Colum; let i =index" #sec>
        <td>{{kbase.DocumentDetails.DocName}}</td>
        <td>{{kbase.ModifiedBy}}</td>
        <td>{{kbase.ModifiedDate}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">

                <select name="select" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="kbase.IsStatus">

                    <option value="true">Active</option>
                    <option value="false">In Active</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <app-file-upload [documentModel]="kbase.DocumentDetails" [isMultipleFile]="true" [model]="kbase" (emitterFile)="fileSelect($event)"></app-file-upload>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Remove" (click)="Delete(kbase.DocumentDetails.Id)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

**TS File:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { knowledgebaseModal } from '../Model/knowledgebase.model';
import { DocumentDetails } from '../Model/document.model';
import { KnowledgeBaseService } from '../Service/knowledgebase.service';
@Component
    ({
        selector: 'knowledgebase',
        templateUrl: './app/QadAdminConfig/Templates/knowledgebase.component.html',
        providers: []
    })

export class KnowledgeBaseComponet implements OnInit {
    docArray: DocumentDetails[] = [];
    kbase: knowledgebaseModal;
    isFile = false;
    result: any;
    data: any;
    Colum: Array<knowledgebaseModal> = [];

    @ViewChild("tmplt") tmpltTbl: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(private _knowledgebaseService: KnowledgeBaseService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFile();
    }

    fileSelect(knowledgemodal: knowledgebaseModal) {
        this.Colum.forEach(x => {
            if (JSON.stringify(x) == JSON.stringify(knowledgemodal))
                x = knowledgemodal;

        });
    }


    AddColum() {
        let model: knowledgebaseModal = new knowledgebaseModal();
        model.DocumentDetails = new DocumentDetails();
        model.DocumentDetails.Id = 0;
        this.Colum.push(model);
    }

    Save() {

        this._knowledgebaseService.Save(this.Colum).subscribe(x => {
            if (x.Success == true) {
                this.result = x;
            }
            this.getFile();
        });

    }

    getFile() {
        this._knowledgebaseService.GetFileContent().subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.Success) {
                    this.Colum = data.Result;
                    console.log(this.Colum);
                }
            });
    }

    Delete(sec: number) {
        if (sec != -1) {
            this.Colum.splice(sec, 1);
            // need to check the document id
            this._knowledgebaseService.Delete(10118).subscribe(x => {
                this.result = x;
            });
            console.log(sec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Delete(i)` (delete the index)

Comment: the colum array has docid, so I need to pass the docid to my delete method for delete the document in db.How can I pass the docid?

Comment: `(click)="Delete(i, kbase.DocumentDetails.Id)"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are passing your Document details Id to the Delete method you have declared, not the index of array that's why you are not getting the correct results.

Try to replace your code with this in Html

```
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Remove" (click)="Delete(i, kbase.DocumentDetails.Id)" />
```

And in TS

```
   Delete(deletedIndex: number, docId: number) {
        if (deletedIndex != -1) {
            this.Colum.splice(deletedIndex, 1);
            this._knowledgebaseService.Delete(docId).subscribe(x => {
                this.result = x;
            });
            console.log(deletedIndex);
        }
    }
```

NB: You should delete the item from view(DOM) after getting successful delete response from your service.